# <p:chips><p:ajax event="itemAdd"> throws exception that itemAdd event is not supported

Tags: jsf, primefaces, chips

I'm seeking assistance in understanding the integration of p:chips with p:ajax.

Upon the completion of a user typing a new two-letter acronym, I aim to validate it within my Managed Bean (MB). This validation is crucial to prevent the duplication of data in the p:chips field. Below, you'll find snippets of both my XHTML code and Managed Bean (MB):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <p:chips id="intinerario" 
                 value="#{MB.dto.ufsper}" 
                 maxlength="2"
                 styleClass="form-control-chips w-100 text-uppercase" 
                 style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;" 
                 widgetVar="chipsWidget">

            <p:ajax event="itemAdd" 
                    listener="#{MB.validarEstadosRepetidosA}" 
                    update="intinerario" />

        </p:chips>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
  public void validarEstadosRepetidosAjax() {
        List<String> estadosAdicionados = dto.getUfsper();
    
        if (temEstadosDuplicados(estadosAdicionados)) {
           
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Não é permitido adicionar o mesmo estado mais de uma vez.", null));
        }
    }
    

    private boolean temEstadosDuplicados(List<String> estados) {
        Set<String> estadosSet = new HashSet<>();
    
        for (String estado : estados) {
            if (!estadosSet.add(estado)) {
              
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        return false;
    }
```

> ERROR 63409 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[facesServlet]           : Servlet.service() for servlet [facesServlet] in context with path [/mytracking] threw exception [/pages/private/moduloFiscal/mdfFiscal/edit/tab/tabPercursoMdf.xhtml @100,32 <p:ajax> Event:itemAdd is not supported.] with root cause

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation on the [`Chips` Ajax behavior events](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/chips?id=ajax-behavior-events). The event `itemAdd` is not supported (as stated in the exception). You probably want to use the `valueChange` event (which is the default).